# Giving one of two valid parses "right of way" in a DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

I've just learned about DCGs and have been really enjoying my early explorations. It's astonishing how much you can get out of a very brief specification. I've bumped into a bit of a wall with what I imagine is a fairly common problem, and was hoping for some expert advice. (Or even novice advice, considering I'm a complete beginner.)

Here's a toy version of my grammar. I've made it pie-focused in honor of 3/14:

```
sent(sent(VP, NP)) --> vp(VP), np(NP).
vp(vp(V)) --> v(V).
vp(vp(V, Qty)) --> v(V), qty(Qty).
np(np(Noun, Qty)) --> qty(Qty), n(Noun).
np(np(Noun)) --> n(Noun).

qty(qty(3)) --> ["3"].
v(v(eat)) --> ["eat"].
n(n(pie)) --> ["pies"].
```

In this grammar, we're worried about quantities, and it matters which the quantity is assigned to, the noun or the verb. So a sentence like "Eat 3 pies" has two valid parses, as seen here:

```
?- sent(X, ["eat", "3", "pies"], []).
X = sent(vp(v(eat)), np(n(pie), qty(3))) ;
X = sent(vp(v(eat), qty(3)), np(n(pie))) ;
```

In a situation like this, I always want the verb to be "awarded" the quantity. My first move, then, would be to simply remove the rule that allows for a quantity to precede a noun. But in another sentence like this one...

```
Bake 4 pies for 3 friends
```

... I would like `friends` to have a `qty(3)` with it.

Is there a technique for resolving these ambiguities?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things you can do.

The easiest is probably to rule out the case `np/2` for the first NP.

```
sent(sent(VP,NP)) --> vp(VP), np(NP), { NP \= np(_,_) }.
sent(sent(VP,NP,PP)) --> vp(VP), np(NP), pp(PP), { NP \= np(_,_) }.

vp(vp(V)) --> v(V).
vp(vp(V,Qty)) --> v(V), qty(Qty).

pp(pp(Prep,NP)) --> prep(Prep), np(NP).

np(np(Noun,Qty)) --> qty(Qty), n(Noun).
np(np(Noun)) --> n(Noun).

qty(qty(3)) --> ["3"].
qty(qty(4)) --> ["4"].

prep(for) --> ["for"].

v(v(bake)) --> ["bake"].
v(v(eat)) --> ["eat"].

n(n(pie)) --> ["pies"].
n(n(friend)) --> ["friends"].
```

This produces:

```
| ?- sent(X,["eat","3","pies"],[]).
X = sent(vp(v(eat),qty(3)),np(n(pie))) ? ;
no
| ?- sent(X,["bake","4","pies","for","3","friends"],[]).
X = sent(vp(v(bake),qty(4)),np(n(pie)),pp(for,np(n(friend),qty(3)))) ? ;
no
```

But it seems hard to justify this design linguistically. Consider "having eaten yesterday 3 pies", "eat for dinner 3 pies", "eat 1 sausage, 2 carrots, and 3 pies" etc.

Comment: "Consider... 'eat for dinner 3 pies'"... oh, I do, every day.

The corpus of sentences I'm trying to parse is pretty strongly constrained, so it's possible I might never have to worry about those types of example sentences you mentioned... but I think it'll be a better decision long-term, so I think I will redesign the linguistics of my grammar.

Glad to know about using raw prolog for that sort of filter, too -- that should be handy at some point. Thanks!